# Jquery ui tabs "onLeave" event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using JQuery UI Tabs to build an user interface. All my tabs contents are loaded via ajax. But I'm faced with a problem: when the user select a tab, the content of the previous selected tab must be saved (via ajax) and I don't see any event like "on leave current" tab (or something like this) to trigger my "save" function. 
edit:
Some snipped code (how I`m build my tabs):

```
var id_p = "a value";
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
    show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up"},
    resizable: false,
    height:140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Yes: function() {
            var dlg = $( this );
            url = "/product/edit.php?id="+id_p;
            $.post(url, function(data) {
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                loadUrl = data.loadUrl;
                title = data.title;
                tabIndex = data.tabIndex;
                $("#product_tabs").tabs("add",loadUrl,title);
                $("#product_tabs").tabs("select", tabIndex);
                initButtons();
                //document.location.reload();
                $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog( "close" );
            });
        },
        No: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please post some reference code or site from where you are using

Comment: What is making your tabs change ? Find that piece of code and call your save function there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the [activate](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate) event and ui.oldPanel to save the information

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        //do ajax stuff with ui.oldPanel
    }
 });
```

However it looks like you might be using a different version of jQuery UI since this version does not seem to have an "add" or "select" method. If you can confirm what version you are using I can provide a better answer.

**For jQuery UI 1.8.16**

Older versions of jQuery do not have the activate event, however you can kind of mimic the functionality above by using the [select](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/tabs/#event-select) event.

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
var previousTab = 0; //init to what tab is selected at start
$( "#tabs" ).on( "tabsselect", function( event, ui ) {
    var previousPanel = $(this).data("tabs").panels[previousTab];
    //save tab info
    previousTab = ui.index; //store new previous tab
});
```

You can see an example at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pw4y6/

Comment: I`m using 1.8.16 version

Comment: I used your tips and everything it`s fine! Thanks Danny!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this page, You can use **ui.oldTab** condition for checking which tab is leave ,

> http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

Comment: "activate" event is not triggered, only "select" event.